# Cairo graphics: Engrave a text in a figure and also making it transparently

Tags: cairo

I have a question regarding Cairo codings (http://cairographics.org/).

I have a filled rectangle (cairo_fill (cr)), how can I cut a hole in the middle of it representing for example the letter "S"?

So basically, I want to "engrave" text in that rectangle but also making the text transparent (like cutting a hole in the rectangle).

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Set the fill rule to even-odd and use cairo_text_path() to get the shape of the letter "S", then cairo_fill() as you do now.